# can't read bmp file perfectly

Tags: c, visual-studio, image-processing, bmp

I am newbie in C ,I write a c code for simply reading a bmp file of 2448x280 pixels having 32 bit depth and writing it into new bmp file. For this I read pixels one by one. I am reading header perfectly , but the problem is  after completing read and write operation on pixels, the current position original image is= 2741814, which is right according to me but result image is have its position = 2903490. So, please tell me where is the mistake.
Here is my code:-

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>


void main(void)
{
    long int length;
    int count,r,c,p;
    FILE *image;
    FILE *result;
    char read_pixels;
    image=fopen("image.bmp","rb");
    result=fopen("result.bmp","w+");

    for(count=0;count<54;count++)
    {

    fread(&read_pixels,1,sizeof(read_pixels),image);
    fprintf(result,"%c",read_pixels);
    }

    for(c=0;c<280;c++)
    {
        for(r=0;r<2448;r++)
        {
            for(p=0;p<4;p++)
            {
                fread(&read_pixels,1,sizeof(read_pixels),image);
                fprintf(result,"%c",read_pixels);
            }
        }
    }

    fseek(image,0,SEEK_CUR);
    length=ftell(image);
    printf("position of image after reading pixels =%d\n",length);
    fseek(result,0,SEEK_CUR);
    length=ftell(result);
    printf("position of result after writing pixels=%d\n",length);
    fclose(image);
    fclose(result);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Do you need to open `result` in binary mode, '"wb"'? Under Windows, files are usually opened in text mode, which transforms any newline `\n` to a carriage-return/newline combo: `\r\n`. I'd also use `putc` instead of `fprintf`, if only to have terser code.